# Inlining an overloaded operator c++

Tags: c++, overloading

Can/should an overloaded operator have to be inlined to gain better efficiency (wrt time or whatever) if that operator will have to be used frequently?

I want to overload the '+' operator to add big vectors very frequently in my code. Hence the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ideally, you'd profile your code and then decide what to inline. There really isn't much of a difference between when you decide to inline regular operators, over overloaded ones.

Comment: +1. And @Gaurish Telang: it is logical to inline adapter methods (methods provided for compatibility, e.g. which calls other method with the same arguments).

Comment: +1. On our team at work, our coding standards discourage inlining of methods in a header file unless there's a provable performance gain.  We also discourage operator overloading of math operators unless the class itself is can be logically thought of as a number.

Comment: +1 to @selbie: operator overloading in most cases only obscures the logic of the code.

Answer (score 6):

If you are adding big vectors, then the overhead of a function call to the plus will be small relative to the time to actually add the two vectors.  So marking the operator+ inline is not likely to improve your overall run time.

Comment: ...or at least not enough to care much about.

Comment: If the operator is used frequently, inlining it will increase the code size, and might decrease the efficiency due to cache-misses.

Answer (score 5):

Let the compiler to decide about optimization.

The keyword `inline` is misleading: the compiler can -in fact- always do what it needs, just like with the *old* `auto` (do you remenber those days?) and `register`.

It's modern meaning is "*defined in header: discard if not used, merge if seen more times*".

Answer (score 2):

The compiler should inline smallish functions for you automatically in release builds.
Much more important is to define a move constructor and move assignment.  If your arrays are very large and you're doing multiple operations at the same time, you can also use expression classes to improve execution speed.

```
template <class left, class right>
struct AddExpr { 
    const left& _left;
    const right& _right;

    AddExpr(const left& Left, const right& Right)
    :_left(Left), _right(Right)
    {assert(left.count() == right.count());}
    int count() const {return _left.count();}
    int operator[](int index) const {return _left[i]+_right[i];}
};
class Array {
    int* data;
    int size;

    int count() const {return size;}
    Array& operator=(AddExpr expr) {
        for(int i=0; i<expr.count(); ++i)
           data[i] = expr[i];
};
AddExpr operator+(const Array& lhs, const Array& rhs) 
{return AddExpr<Array, Array>(lhs, rhs);}
AddExpr operator+(const Array& lhs, const Expr& rhs) 
{return AddExpr<Array, Expr>(lhs, rhs);}
AddExpr operator+(const Expr& lhs, const Array& rhs) 
{return AddExpr<Expr, Array>(lhs, rhs);}
AddExpr operator+(const Expr& lhs, const Expr& rhs) 
{return AddExpr<Expr, Expr>(lhs, rhs);}

int main() {
    Array a, b, c, d;
    Array c = (a+b) + (c+d);  //awesome on lines like this
}
```

This removes all the temporary objects, and greatly improves cache efficiency.  But I've completely forgotten what this technique is called.